# Compare bank account statements in xlsx or csv file format to find any matching transactions

Tags: python, bash, csv, comparison

I have multiple .xlsx bank account statements that I merge and sort, in order to manually compare and match any transactions made between my accounts. The intent is to parse all transactions made prior to importing them into GnuCash, so that no duplicate transaction records appear in my account registers.

As of now I have made a bash script that parse the .csv file created by me after the manual comparison of the merged .xlsx files. A combination of sed and awk is used to produce the .qif file needed when importing into GnuCash.

I would like some help automating my manual comparison of the transactions, since I find myself unable to successfully parse the matching transactions using sed or awk.

My bank statements have the following format:

```
Date recorded;Date occurred;Verification number;Memo;Amount;Balance
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;-5000;3470.69
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-200;8470.69
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-1730;8670.69
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;3788765004S;SALARY;10000.69;10400.69
2014-04-24;2014-04-24;5484384195;PHARMACY /14-04-23;-79;400
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5434473478;GAS STATION/14-04-22;-521;479
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5487473797;GROCERY STORE/14-04-22;-661;1000
```

When I have all bank statements merged and sorted, I have added a column with the source bank statement account number:

```
Date recorded;Date occurred;Verification number;Memo;Amount;Balance;Source account
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;-5000;3470.69;123456789
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;5000;10000;543219876              # Merged from my second accounts statement
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-200;8470.69;123456789
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;200;1930;987654321                 # Merged from my third accounts statement
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-1730;8670.69;123456789
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;1730;1730;987654321                # Merged from my third accounts statement
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;3788765004S;SALARY;10000.69;10400.69;123456789
2014-04-24;2014-04-24;5484384195;PHARMACY /14-04-23;-79;400;123456789
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5434473478;GAS STATION/14-04-22;-521;479;123456789
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5487473797;GROCERY STORE/14-04-22;-661;1000;123456789
```

What I need help with achieving is parsing the file with the merged bank statements, so that transactions between my accounts are found. Any transactions (lines in the file) where columns Date recorded, Date occurred, Verification number, Memo and Amount (disregarding negative amount symbol when comparing the two lines) match should processed like this: 1) Keep source account transaction line in file, 2) Add new column ("Destination account") with destination accounts account number to source account transaction line 3) Delete destination account transaction line from file.

As an example - this is a match:

```
Date recorded;Date occurred;Verification number;Memo;Amount;Balance;Source account
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;-5000;3470.69;123456789           # Source account
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;5000;10000;543219876              # Destination account
```

When these two lines producing the transaction have been processed the output in the file should be:

```
Date recorded;Date occurred;Verification number;Memo;Amount;Balance;Source account;Destination account
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;-5000;3470.69;123456789;543219876
```

After all transactions in my example of merged bank account statements have been processed, the final output should be a file with the following lines:

```
Date recorded;Date occurred;Verification number;Memo;Amount;Balance;Source account;Destination account
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;-5000;3470.69;123456789;543219876
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-200;8470.69;123456789;987654321
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-1730;8670.69;123456789;987654321
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;3788765004S;SALARY;10000.69;10400.69;123456789;
2014-04-24;2014-04-24;5484384195;PHARMACY /14-04-23;-79;400;123456789;
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5434473478;GAS STATION/14-04-22;-521;479;123456789;
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5487473797;GROCERY STORE/14-04-22;-661;1000;123456789;
```

Note: These four transactions aren't *transactions between my accounts* - they should be kept in the file with the added column "Destination account" left empty.

```
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;3788765004S;SALARY;10000.69;10400.69;123456789;
2014-04-24;2014-04-24;5484384195;PHARMACY /14-04-23;-79;400;123456789;
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5434473478;GAS STATION/14-04-22;-521;479;123456789;
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5487473797;GROCERY STORE/14-04-22;-661;1000;123456789;
```

Any solution using tools compatible with my current bash script (or perhaps a solution using pythons pandas library?) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the required output it doesn't look like you've disregarded any transactions with negative amount figures.

Comment: Disregard that sentence. It isn't crystal clear as I read it after a good nights sleep. To clarify: A match is two lines with matching Date recorded, Date occurred, Verification number, Memo, Amount (disregarding negative amount figure).

Comment: ...when a match has been found, then add the account number of the  account receiving to a new column ("To account") on the line of transaction sending, and delete the receiving accounts line from the list/file.

Comment: Your required output still doesn't match what you've said. Taking the `MORTGAGE` transactions merged as an example, everything matches according to your criteria except the `Amount` (whether you disregard that one is negative and the other isn't or not). Also, exactly what's a sending transaction?

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my first language. I have rephrased my original question, trying to exemplify my criteria for matches and elaborate on how matches should be processed to produce the final output. Also, column headers "From account" and "To account" is now replaced by "Source account" and "Destination account" as the header "From account" might have been confusing... 

As to the term "sending transaction" I used - it is the part of the transaction (line) that is seen on the source account bank statement. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the processing of the transactions records described in your updated question.

It first creates a dictionary of type `defaultdict(list)` from the input csv file which has keys based on the criteria described for transaction matching. All transactions with the same key are stored in an associated `list`.

Afterwards it goes through the list of transactions gathered for each key in a pair-wise fashion and creates merged transactions records from them that have the additional destination account field from the second transaction's source account added. Each merged transaction record created is then written to the output csv file.

Transactions which aren't paired simply become merged records with an empty destination fields. Transactions which are paired are only merged if the sign of two amounts differ, otherwise they are treated as two unpaired transactions as previously described.

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
import csv
from itertools import imap, izip_longest

# A couple of utility string conversion functions.
def rename(name):
    """ Convert csv column name to a valid namedtuple fieldname which must be a
    valid Python identifier. Not exhaustive, but good enough for the headers
    shown (and is reversable, see below).
    """
    return name.lower().replace(' ', '_')

def undo_rename(name):
    """ Convert munged namedtuple fieldname back to a csv column name. """
    return name.replace('_', ' ').capitalize()

banktrans_filename = 'banktrans.csv'
banktrans_merged_filename = 'banktransmerged.csv'
DELIMITER = ';'
matched_trans = defaultdict(list)

with open(banktrans_filename, 'rb') as banktrans_file:
    reader = csv.reader(banktrans_file, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    # create namedtuple fieldnames from csv header row
    fieldnames = [rename(columname) for columname in next(reader)]
    Transaction = namedtuple('Transaction', fieldnames)
    for transact in imap(Transaction._make, reader):
        match_key = (transact.date_recorded, transact.date_occurred,
                     transact.verification_number, transact.memo,
                     # disregard any leading minus sign in amount field
                     transact.amount[transact.amount.startswith('-'):])
        matched_trans[match_key].append(transact)

with open(banktrans_merged_filename, 'wb') as banktrans_merged_file:
    writer = csv.writer(banktrans_merged_file, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    # merged tranactions have an additonal fieldname at the end
    mergedfieldnames = fieldnames + [rename('Destination account')]
    MergedTransaction = namedtuple('MergedTransaction', mergedfieldnames)
    # write header row
    writer.writerow([undo_rename(fieldname) for fieldname in mergedfieldnames])
    # merge pairs of matched transactions
    for match_key, transacts in sorted(matched_trans.items()):
        for trans_pair in izip_longest(*([iter(transacts)]*2)):
            if trans_pair[1] is None:  # unmatched trans, copy & add empty col
                merged_transact = MergedTransaction._make(trans_pair[0] + ('',))
            elif (trans_pair[0].amount.startswith('-') ==
                  trans_pair[1].amount.startswith('-')):  # amts have same sign?
                # records shouldn't be merged, treat as two unmatched trans
                merged_transact = MergedTransaction._make(trans_pair[0] + ('',))
                writer.writerow(merged_transact)
                merged_transact = MergedTransaction._make(trans_pair[1] + ('',))
                writer.writerow(merged_transact)
                continue  # skip remainder of loop
            else:  # merge pair by making source of the second the dest account
                merged_transact = MergedTransaction._make(
                    trans_pair[0] + (trans_pair[1].source_account,))
            writer.writerow(merged_transact)    

print('merged transactions saved to file: ' + repr(banktrans_merged_filename))
```

Resulting output file's contents:

```
Date recorded;Date occurred;Verification number;Memo;Amount;Balance;Source account;Destination account
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5434473478;GAS STATION/14-04-22;-521;479;123456789;
2014-04-23;2014-04-22;5487473797;GROCERY STORE/14-04-22;-661;1000;123456789;
2014-04-24;2014-04-24;5484384195;PHARMACY /14-04-23;-79;400;123456789;
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;3788765004S;SALARY;10000.69;10400.69;123456789;
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-1730;8670.69;123456789;987654321
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5284690010;SAVINGS;-200;8470.69;123456789;987654321
2014-04-25;2014-04-25;5629374859;MORTGAGE;-5000;3470.69;123456789;543219876
```

Comment: You're welcome. The better and more precisely you can describe what needs to be done, the more likely it becomes that you'll be able to get something that can accomplish it. ;-)

Comment: Hello again! Having used the script for the last few months I have noticed that the following example of two transactions are parsed "the wrong way":

<!-- language: lang-none -->
2015-03-30;2015-03-30;5284690019;BANK FEE;-25;114.5;123456789
2015-03-30;2015-03-30;5284690019;BANK FEE;-25;3273.81;987654321

The transactions are parsed as a transaction between my two accounts (due to the script disregarding any leading minus sign in amount field?):

<!-- language: lang-none -->
2015-03-30;2015-03-30;5284690019;BANK FEE;-25;114.5;123456789;987654321

Comment: Those two transactions _should_ be merged because they both have the same `transact.verification_number`, `transact.amount` (whether the minus sign is being ignored or not), as well as the other criteria in `match_key`. What exactly is wrong with the way they were parsed.

Comment: Perhaps two transactions shouldn't be merged unless their signs differ. i.e. `25` and `-25` or `-25` and `25` yes, but not `25` and `25` or `-25` and `-25` no.

Comment: They are parsed as I initially intended the script to parse them. But as I use the script I'm having second thoughts as to how a match should be defined. Both transactions are separate transactions as they are the monthly bank fee drawn from all my accounts (using the same transaction data - apart from the source account number specified in my bank statement). But they aren't one transaction between the two accounts and should therefore be disregarded as a matching transaction between these two accounts...

Comment: Just need to define some way to tell them apart from the ones you do want matched. How are they different from the rest?

Comment: As to your comment on matching transactions with the same leading sign on both transaction lines; Thats it! A matching transaction shouldn't have matching positive/negative amounts on both the source- and the destination account. The implied pattern is that the source account have a negative amount (or a positive amount) and that the opposite should be expected on the destination account.

Comment: Doing something like that could probably be done during the merging step. Frankly, there's very little motivation for me to modify my current answer since you never even bothered to up-vote it. Plus it seems reasonable to expect your Python skills to have improved enough by now to be able to fix it yourself. Why don't you try doing that and ask another question if you get stuck.

Comment: No problem, I'm trying my best to sort it out myself. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I can't up-vote your answer as that requires 15 in reputation. I'll do it once I have the needed reputation!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have these line items loaded into a list of lists...

```
matcher = dict()
for li in line_items:
    # use Verification as key, append Amount and Account
    matcher.setdefault(li[2], []).append((li[5], li[7]))
# then sort these by amount so that "from" is first (negative value means "from") 
for k in matcher.keys():
    matcher[k].sort()
[...]
# later, can obtain accounts using Verification...
# assuming "v" has value of Verification number
from_acct, to_acct = [i[1] for i in matcher.get(v, ((None, None), (None, None)))]
```